# Avoid debugger to jump to exception (using an attribute?)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, exception, attributes

I have the situation, where I cannot prevent an exception from being raised. And I am trying to avoid, that Visual Studio Debugger jumps to this exception. Important: I generally want all the exceptions to be active in the VS exception settings. There are just a few specific methods, I'd like to ignore.

(Of course I am looking forward to improve the code, to prevent them from being raised in first place. But for this post here, I'd like to ignore that and focus on the actual question).

What I've tried so far are some attributes in that test code, without success:

```
    public static void Main(params string[] args)
    {
        bool canConnect = TryConnect("anyAddress");
        Console.WriteLine($"Can Connect: {canConnect}");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    [DebuggerNonUserCode]
    [DebuggerHidden]
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    private static bool TryConnect(string ipAddress)
    {
        try
        {
            SecondaryClass.Connect(ipAddress);
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}

/// <summary>
/// this might be third pary or something else, raising an exception.
/// </summary>
public class SecondaryClass
{
    [DebuggerNonUserCode]
    [DebuggerHidden]
    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public static void Connect(string address)
    {
        throw new Exception("Can't connect");
    }
}
```

But still, VStudio jumps to the assignment canConnect = TryConnect showing the exception.

What could I do to avoid this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Your post states:

> I have the situation, where I cannot prevent an exception from being raised.

This implies that the call is being made from a different module (otherwise you *could* prevent it). So, let's say that `ThirdPartyLibrary.dll` has a method named `Connect` that throws `System.TimeoutException`. I would suggest that you try editing the *conditions* for `TimeoutException` and disable the **Break When Thrown** property for that specific module only.

[image: exception properties popup]

The `TimeoutException` will still be thrown regardless of any setting; there's no way to "suppress" it in the sense of making it not happen at all. What there is to do is handle that exception in a manner that achieves your stated objective:

> There are just a few specific methods, I'd like to ignore.

**TESTBENCH**

This will demonstrate three variations depending on the **Module Name** + **Not Equals** condition, and also the `wantBreak` variable in the `Main` method.

```
public static void Main(params string[] args)
{
    bool wantBreak = false;
    try
    {
        ThirdPartyClass.Connect("anyAddress");
    }
    catch
    {
        Debug.Assert(
            !wantBreak, 
            "Breaks on this condition if 'wantBreak' is set to true");
    }  
}
```

1. **Before adding condition** the debugger breaks in external module.

[image: Breaks in external module]

2. **After adding condition** the debugger breaks in your code, but only if `wantBreak` is set.

[image: breakpoint in local code]

3. You can **disable the local debug assertion** by setting `wantBreak = false`. Now the `Main` method will run to completion with no debugger breaks at all.

---

**Debugger Attributes and Just My Code**

Your posted code also shows that you tried Debugger Attributes. To explain why those *didn't* work in your case, first remove the condition and go back to the default. Once you do this *the debugger is going to break "somewhere"* you can only change *where*.

[image: exception setting]

**[DebuggerNonUserCode]** If `ThirdPartyLibrary` is already [non-user-code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/just-my-code?view=vs-2022#BKMK__NET_Framework_Just_My_Code) *or* decorated with the `[DebuggerNonUserCode]` attribute, then the setting of **Just My Code** determines whether the debugger breaks in the module *or* in the local code.

[image: Just My Code comparison]

**[DebuggerHidden]** determines whether the code breaks in `TryConnect` *or* in `Main`.

[image: DebuggerHidden comparison]

Importantly, even if you were to `[DebuggerHide]` the `Main` method (I don't recommend this) it wouldn't prevent the debugger from breaking.

```
[DebuggerHidden]
public static void Main(params string[] args)
{
    bool wantBreak = true;
    try
    {
        TryConnect("anyAddress");
    }
    catch
    {
        Debug.Assert(
            !wantBreak, 
            "Breaks here if 'wantBreak' is set to true");
    }  
}
```

Only *now* the debugger can't find a debug symbol to break on so you get this:

[image: all code is hidden (pathological)]

As you can see, there are many permutations and hopefully this sheds some light on a few.

Comment: I see there is no simple solution to my need, to break for the an exception in one case, but not in the other. However, you explainations were very helpful, thanks for that. Rating up, but still waiting and still chasing to avoid my exceptions in first place.